# Snake game using FPGA (NEXYS2)

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am planning to make a snake game using the NEXYS2 board in VHDL and display it on LED Matrix something similar to this in the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niQmNYPiPw0 but still I don't know where to begin. How would I go about implementing this in VHDL?

Comment: this is not even a question

Answer (score 2):

Beyond designing and wiring up the hardware (connectors, LED matrices and such) and the actual design of the game (the rules and what inputs cause which outputs), you start by breaking down the design constraints into blocks which you then write as VHDL. For example, you might have a display output component that takes pixel change events and writes the screen state to the display (or maybe it takes the whole screen state, and only handles the interface logic to the display). You might have a game logic component, and a controller interface component.

Once you decide what each block should do, you have to decide how it will do that with data flow and control logic, which you write in VHDL (you need to know the basic syntax and functionality of VHDL first!).

Then the synthesizer translates your RTL description into an implementation of flip flops and look up tables, and the place&route tool figures out where to put and connect these units using the actual resources of the FPGA you are targeting, generating a binary configuration file.

The configuration file is loaded onto the FPGA and (assuming you have the hardware hooked up right and your VHDL and design is perfect) you have a working snake game.

Simple, right?

In order to get useful answers here, you need to get to the "writing the VHDL" stage, write some VHDL, see it fail to function according to your constraints, then ask a question about that.